# Constructing matrices with the given eigenvalue and eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

There are several similar questions:

(a) If possible, write down a 5 × 5 real matrix with −1 as its only real eigenvalue and where the eigenspace with eigenvalue −1 has dimension 3.

(b) If possible, write down a 5 × 5 real matrix with −1 as its only real eigenvalue and where the eigenspace with eigenvalue −1 has dimension 5.

(c) If possible, write down a 5 × 5 real matrix with −1 as its only real eigenvalue and where the eigenspace with eigenvalue −1 has dimension 1 and the generalized eigenspace with eigenvalue −1 has dimension 3.

(d) If possible, write down a 5 × 5 real matrix with −1 as its only real eigenvalue and where the eigenspace with eigenvalue −1 has dimension 1 and the generalized eigenspace with eigenvalue
−1 has dimension 4.

Can anyone give me some hints for each one or provide a general way to slove all of them and other similar questions?

Comment: I think maybe we can use J.C.F but don't know how...

Comment: Yes, you can use JCF. In fact, these questions are meant to test your understanding of its structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the first question. Try to adapt the answer to the other questions.

An example of a matrix that satisfies the property mentioned in (a) is$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&-1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: i know how to proceed the first two,but what about c) and d), what does the dimension of generalized eigenspace imply? How to use the dimension of the generalized eigenspace ?

Comment: Here's an answer to (c):$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&0&0&0\\0&-1&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$